# Viewing content with keyboard popup in phone browser

Tags: css, keyboard

I have created a web page with input fields. But, when I click on the keyboard while viewing on a phone browser, the view is completely disoriented. How can I correct it?

Answer (score 0):

The question is not much clear.

From what i understood, your design is not yet responsive/ mobile-friendly.

You should use [bootstrap grid system](http://getbootstrap.com) or use your custom media query to make the web page responsive.